# Who passed the arguments to the parameters of the complition handler closure?

Tags: ios, swift, functional-programming, closures, completionhandler

```
func startUpdates(from start: Date, 
      withHandler handler: @escaping CMPedometerHandler)

typealias CMPedometerHandler = (CMPedometerData?, Error?) -> Void
```

The above function retrieves the pedometer data from your iOS device. When I called the function the only argument I need passed to is the parameter `from start`.

Who actually initialized the parameter list of the completion handler closure? The `startUpdates` function I've called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I called the function the only argument I need to passed to is the parameter from start

**That's not true.**

You have to pass also the closure as second parameter. The closure itself is called by the `startUpdates` function after doing its work and passes two parameters back, an optional `Data` and an optional `Error` instance.

The functional programming is a very convenient way to be able to run arbitrary code (in the closure).

You can declare the closure separately

```
let result : CMPedometerHandler = { data, error in
    if let error = error { print(error); return }
    // do something with the data 

}

startUpdates(from: Date(), withHandler: result)
```

or inline

```
startUpdates(from: Date(), withHandler: { data, error in
    if let error = error { print(error); return }
    // do something with the data 

})
```

or with trailing closure syntax

```
startUpdates(from: Date()) { data, error in
    if let error = error { print(error); return }
    // do something with the data 

}
```

Comment: ! ah I got it, I have to pass the closure as argument to the function, the closure is how I want to process the CMPedometerData ane Error later in the run time, but the the initialization of CMPedometerData ane Error will be done by the function. Its seems as if I passed a predicate to a it to guide how to process the data.

Comment: Yes, it's similar like passing a predicate